# Video Training for Magento Beginner

Tags: learn-magento

I would like to learn the fundamentals of setting up a store via the back end using video training. A step by step training is ideal, starting with an introductory overview of the back end, then progress in to more detail through the basics of setting up a store including

- Applying a theme
- Adding products & categories (in depth)
- Managing page layouts
- Adjusting the nav bar links
- Setting up taxes
- Connecting paypal express checkout

So all the fundamentals required to get a basic store up and running on a host server of my choosing.
Ideally the back end changes need to be shown in the front end during training so one can see the effect each change has.
I ask for video as I am a visual learner and I find this is the fastest way for me to learn the basics before I progress into the deeper aspects such as customisation and programming.

Answer (score 1):

I have Learn Basic Magento Concept Using `Magento U`.

You can find the Links of videos

1. Quick Start to Magento Customization - Part 1 => [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtBaozxkFgI)
2. Quick Start to Magento Customization - Part 2 => [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmQ1IfohDWk)
3. Quick Start to Magento Customization - Part 3 => [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mh9VxfUZTNk)

You can Also read the Blogs which is good

1. http://magestudyguide.com/
2. http://blog.magestore.com/magento-training/magento-certification/

You can also refer the Magento Default Study Guide.